# Sum values on column A based on a string criteria in column B

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following columns:

```
A       B
23      75001
42      94
1       13
3       75002
4       12
```

I would like to sum values of column A if the two first digits of the number in column B is matching `75` or `12`.

In this example, the result would be `23 + 3 + 4` = `30`.

I tried to use `=SUMIFS` but it looks like I can only use a criteria based on a integer ...

Do you have an idea how to do this ?

EDIT : I am trying to make a VBA macro

Answer (score 3):

One option using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*((--LEFT(B1:B5,2)=75)+(--LEFT(B1:B5,2)=12)))
```

[image]

Similarly, using `FILTER` if you have access to it:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A1:A5,((--LEFT(B1:B5,2)=75)+(--LEFT(B1:B5,2)=12))))
```

Even shorter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*(LEFT(B1:B5,2)={"75","12"}))
```

or if you don't want to put quotes around the numbers

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*(--LEFT(B1:B5,2)={75,12}))
```

though keeping the quotes around `75` and `12` is a better approach if you have one or more blank cells in B1:B5.

Comment: Since the criteria are the same length, you could also use an array to shorten the formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*(LEFT(B1:B5,2)={"75","12"}))`

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for your answer... I am trying to make a macro and I am not sure the "shorter" solution you gave me is working....

Comment: I tried a VBA macro "
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct ("A1:A5" * ((--Left("B1:B5", 2) = 75) + (--Left("B1:B5", 2) = 12)))" but I received the error "type mismatch"

Comment: Use `Evaluate` here.

Comment: e.g.: `Debug.Print [SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*(--LEFT(B1:B5,2)={75,12}))]`. Could be nicely applied to a `With` statement to apply to the apporpriate worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"|75";"|12"},"|"&B1:B5)),A1:A5,0))
```

Though, if you'd have ExcelO365, you could use `SUM()` instead. If you need this to be VBA you could mimic this quite easily. Don't let it be mistaken, the other answer is the go-to method, however, this way you could easily add more criteria if need be.

To mimic this in VBA you could use an array and `Select Case` if you would need to add more criteria in the future:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long, sm As Double, arr As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:B" & lr).Value
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Select Case Left(arr(x, 2), 2)
            Case "75", "12": sm = sm + arr(x, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    Debug.Print sm
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @JvdV for the macro but I get a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range." :(

Comment: Please do some troubleshooting first yourself. The code is tried and worked based on the sample data you have given us. Sit down, try to understand the code and make sure you are basing this of the right worksheet. It's hard to troubleshoot and help you based on your comments alone.

Comment: Maybe I need to make others changes... in my program, the columns I am using are E and J so I replaced A1:B by E1:J...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function countOccLeft(arr As Variant, Cr1 As String, Cr2 As String) As Long
   Dim dict As Object, i As Long: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
     If Left(arr(i, 2), 2) = Cr1 Or Left(arr(i, 2), 2) = Cr2 Then
        If Not dict.Exists("key_sum") Then
            dict.Add "key_sum", arr(i, 1)
        Else
            dict("key_sum") = dict("key_sum") + arr(i, 1)
        End If
     End If
   Next i
   countOccLeft = dict("key_sum")
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testCountOccL()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, strSearch As String, lastRow As Long
  
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value
   
   Debug.Print countOccLeft(arr, "75", "12")
End Sub
```